cant write value an input element in .md file content on Angular
In Angular, I am retrieving the content of a .md file from the backend. This .md content includes input tags like . I can add these inputs to a previously created form, but I am unable to enter data into these inputs. Is this something Angular does for security reasons, or is it an error?
I searched a few things but i cant find any reason

there is some built-in XSS protections.  Include the code you use to populate the inputs. There are other ways to dynamically render components.  You don't need to return actual markup/tags from the backend.
